# How to update a record in LocalStorage in React function components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React JS, and I'm trying to edit some values from LocalStorage, in the console I can see it has updated but it doesn't update in the front end.
I know there are a few similar threads but none is really helping me. Can someone please put me in the right direction?

```
// getting the values of local storage
const getDatafromLS = () => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem('reg');
    if (data) {
        return JSON.parse(data);
    }
    else {
        return []
    }
}

const Test2 = () => {

    const [regArr, setRegArr] = useState(getDatafromLS());
    const [reg, setReg] = useState({ name: "" });
    const [editForm, setEditForm] = useState(false);// edit form
    const [id, setId] = useState();// id state

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const name = e.target.name;
        const value = e.target.value;
        setReg({ ...reg, [name]: value });
    }

    const { name } = reg;
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (name === "") {
            alert("INPUT can not be empty")
        } else {
            setRegArr([...regArr, { name }]);
        }
        setReg({ name: "" })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('reg', JSON.stringify(regArr));
    }, [regArr])

    const handleDelete = (i) => {
        let newdataArr = [...regArr]
        newdataArr.splice(i, 1)
        setRegArr(newdataArr)
    }

    const handleEdit = (i) => {
        setEditForm(true);
        setId(i);
        const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reg'));
        setReg(data[i]);//Set the clicked record in textfield
    }
    
    const handleEditSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Checking  ', id);
    
        const newList = regArr.map(li => (
            li.id === id ? {...li, name: reg} : li)
            )
        setReg(newList)
        localStorage.setItem('reg', JSON.stringify(reg));
        setReg('');
        setEditForm(false);     
    }
    return (
        <div>
            {editForm === false && (
                <div>
                    <label>New Registration</label>
                    <input type='text' name='name' onChange={handleChange} value={reg.name} placeholder='Name ...' />
                    <button type='submit' onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
                </div>
            )}
            {editForm === true && (
                <div>
                    <label>Update Registration</label>
                    <input type='text' name='name' onChange={handleChange} value={reg.name} placeholder='Name ...' />
                    <button type='submit' onClick={handleEditSubmit}>Update</button>
                </div>
            )}
            <p></p>
            <Test3 test3={regArr} handleDelete={handleDelete} handleEdit={handleEdit} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test2;
```

I have used a seperate component for result output.

```
const Test3 = ({ test3, handleDelete, handleEdit }) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        test3 && test3.map((rg, index) => {
                            return (
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{rg.name}</td>
                                    <td><button onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}>Delete</button></td>
                                    <td><button onClick={() => handleEdit(index)}>Edit</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Test3;
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm trying to update an added record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, this makes more sens to me :

```js
const handleEditSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('Checking  ', id);

  const newList = regArr.map((li) =>
    li.id === id ? { ...li, name: reg.name } : li
  );
  setRegArr(newList); // Update regArr state, not reg state
  localStorage.setItem('reg', JSON.stringify(newList)); // Save newList, not reg
  setReg({ name: '' }); // Clear the reg state
  setEditForm(false);
};
```

Also when you click to edit you set the `id` state to the index of the map iteration then, you compare this id to the value of id propery of each element of in `regArr` but they are not the same thing.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bessie-rj5zvz) you can find a working example. I had to make some changes 
clear your local storage before running the code.

Comment: I agree with your code but for some reason it doesn't work. I have literally copy and pasted your code in case I was missing it up but no joy.

Comment: For some reason 'newList' doesn't change, it has the same data.

Comment: @Tony what do mean by doesn't change ? is `regArr` has the expected data and `id` has the expected value when the function runs?

Comment: Yes it does. After its loop over the map I thought it should changed it's value to new inserted value.

Comment: newList must have the same as `regArr` expect for the one that has the same id value as `is` it has a new name `reg.name`

Comment: `expect for the one that has the same id value` this is what I'm saying newList has no changes at all, even for the new name `reg.name`

Comment: so `li.id === id` is falsy somehow

Comment: Seems like it. I'm checking it in console it's correct `id` .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254397/discussion-between-hatana-and-tony).

Comment: @Tony have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event listener to query whether something has changed and call your function again. Or you save it directly to your state when you change it.

```
window.onstorage = () => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("sampleList")));
};
```